# Calling predefined service from python script

Tags: python, rosservice, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am wondering how to pass an arguments when trying to call rosservice from python script.

I have this server called bcap_service which takes 2 arguments. (This is bcap.srv)

```
int32 func_id
variant[] vntArgs
---
int32 HRESULT
variant vntRet
```

(This is variant.msg)

```
int16 vt
string value
```

and I am trying to pass these arguments.

```
rosservice call /bcap_service '{func_id: 3, vntArgs: [{vt: 8, value: "b-CAP"}, {vt: 8, value: "CaoProv.DENSO.VRC"}, {vt: 8, value: "localhost"}, {vt: 8, value: ""}] }'
```

I have tried assigning them to variables. Tried writing like a YAML and had no results. Here is my code:

```
def gripper_control():
        rospy.wait_for_service('bcap_service')
             
        func_id = 3
               
        vt = 8
        value_1 = 'value: b-CAP'
        value_2 = 'CaoProv.DENSO.VRC'
        value_3 = 'localhost'
        value_4 = ''
    
        vntArgs = [vt, value_1, vt, value_2, vt, value_3, vt, value_4]
    
        rospy.ServiceProxy('bcap_service', func_id, vntArgs)
```

After running the code, I get error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/denso_robot_bringup/move_group_python_interface_cobotta.py", line 224, in <module>
    gripper_control()
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/denso_robot_bringup/move_group_python_interface_cobotta.py", line 197, in gripper_control
    rospy.ServiceProxy('bcap_service', func_id, vntArgs)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 404, in __init__
    super(ServiceProxy, self).__init__(name, service_class)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/service.py", line 59, in __init__
    self.request_class = service_class._request_class
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_request_class'
```

EDIT:

Full code below:

```
import sys
import copy
import rospy
import math
import moveit_commander
import moveit_msgs.msg
import geometry_msgs.msg
from geometry_msgs.msg import Pose, Point
from math import pi
from std_msgs.msg import String
from bcap_service.srv import *


def gripper_control():

    rospy.wait_for_service('bcap_service')
    try:
        
        #create handler to call the service
        bcap_service = rospy.ServiceProxy('bcap_service', bcap)
        print "ServiceProxy success ..."

        #define the request
        func_id = 3
        vt = 8
        value_1 = 'value: b-CAP'
        value_2 = 'CaoProv.DENSO.VRC'
        value_3 = 'localhost'
        value_4 = ''
        vntArgs = [vt, value_1, vt, value_2, vt, value_3, vt, value_4]
        print "Assignment success ..."
        print vntArgs

        #call the service by passing the request to the handler
        #it doesn't require to have the same names as in the .srv
        #But I did it for clarity
        response = bcap_service(func_id, vntArgs)
        print "rosservice call success"

        #store the response in some variables
        result1 = response.HRESULT
        result2 = response.vntRet

        #return the whole response
        return response

    except rospy.ServiceException, e:
        print "Service call failed: %s"%e
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':

    rospy.init_node('cobotta_node')
    robot = moveit_commander.RobotCommander()
    scene = moveit_commander.PlanningSceneInterface()
    group = moveit_commander.MoveGroupCommander("arm")

    gripper_control()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321758/calling-predefined-service-from-python-script/) by [Tulga](https://answers.ros.org/users/41017/tulga/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Update

I was able to solve this problem thanks to this [post](https://github.com/DENSORobot/denso_robot_ros/issues/21).

```
Variant type is defined as a message file in bcap_service package.
```

Here is simplified code:

```
rospy.wait_for_service('bcap_service')
    
    try:
        
        bcapReq = bcap_service.srv.bcapRequest()
        bcapReq.func_id = 3
        bcapReq.vntArgs.append(variant(vt=8, value="b-CAP"))
        bcapReq.vntArgs.append(variant(vt=8, value="CaoProv.DENSO.VRC"))
        bcapReq.vntArgs.append(variant(vt=8, value="localhost"))
        bcapReq.vntArgs.append(variant(vt=8, value=""))

        bcapSrv = rospy.ServiceProxy('bcap_service', bcap)
        response = bcapSrv(bcapReq)

        # print 'HRESULT:', response.HRESULT
        # print 'vntRet.vt:', response.vntRet.vt
        # print 'vntRet.value:', response.vntRet.value

    except rospy.ServiceException, e:
        print "Service call failed: %s"%e
```

Cheers.

---

Originally posted by [Tulga](https://answers.ros.org/users/41017/tulga/) with karma: 16 on 2019-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rospy.ServiceProxy()` requires as argument the name of the service and its type. This is used to create a handler that you can use as a function that needs the srv request as arguments. Have a look at the [ros tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28python%29#rospy_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingServiceClient.Writing_the_Client_Node), it is well documented.

I haven't tested but this should do what you want :

```
def gripper_control():
    try:
        rospy.wait_for_service('bcap_service')

        #define the request
        func_id = 3
        vt = 8
        value_1 = 'value: b-CAP'
        value_2 = 'CaoProv.DENSO.VRC'
        value_3 = 'localhost'
        value_4 = ''
        vntArgs = [vt, value_1, vt, value_2, vt, value_3, vt, value_4]

        #create handler to call the service
        call_bcap = rospy.ServiceProxy('bcap_service', bcap)

        #call the service by passing the request to the handler
        #it doesn't require to have the same names as in the .srv
        #But I did it for clarity
        response = call_bcap(func_id, vntArgs)

        #store the response in some variables
        result1 = response.HRESULT
        result2 = response.vntRet

        #return the whole response
        return response

    except rospy.ServiceException, e:
        print "Service call failed: %s"%e
```

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2019-04-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tulga](https://answers.ros.org/users/41017/tulga/) on 2019-04-25**:
Thank you for the quick reply. Error `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'vt'` is still there. I suppose now it has problem with defining `vntArgs = [vt, value_1, vt, value_2, vt, value_3, vt, value_4]`

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-04-25**:
Can you give your full code please ?
Also maybe try to modify the `.srv` so that `vntArgs` and `vntRet` are arrays of strings instead of mixed types (because you just have the same value `vt` before each different string which doesn't really make sense)

**Comment by [Tulga](https://answers.ros.org/users/41017/tulga/) on 2019-04-25**:
I edited post with full code. Is it alright to modify predefined services? If it is okay, I will change type to string or some other type.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-04-25**:
I actually think the error is just related to the `variant` type. It seems to require some workaround to use this with python. So if you must use this specific service you should consider do that in `C++` instead of python or maybe try to wrap some `C++` code using `Boost.Python`